# Difference between using App.js and ReactDOM.render in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

There's a component named `TestComponent` below, I wanted to ask what's the difference between me using `React.render` to render the test component in the same page and me using the `TestComponent` in the App.js

**Scenario 1**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class TestComponent extends Component {
componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Great");
}

render() {
    return (
        <p>
            {this.props.test}
        </p>
    );
 }}
ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent test="new" />);
```

**Scenario 2**

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import TestComponent from "./components/TestComponent"

class Apps extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
        <div>

             <TestComponent test={this.props.test}/>

        </div>
    );

}}
ReactDOM.render(<App test="new" />);
```

Comment: the only difference is the wrapping `div` that you have in `Apps`. But you can return just `TestComponent` and the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. The only difference is that in scenario one, you are rendering a component and in scenario two you are rendering a component that itself returns, as something to be rendered, another component.
So there really is no difference.

It's like saying

```
int i = 3;
return i * i;
```

and alternatively doing

```
int i = 1;
return (i + 2) * (i + 2);
```

So it is really a matter of composition. Scenario one renders a component that is not composed of any other and scenario two renders a component that is composed of other components.